# Get Object nested property using dot separated string

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Is there in Flex any utility to get object nested property using dot separated string like this:

```
SomeUtil.getObjectProperty(object, "child.property");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can roll your own, assuming object is a dynamic object :

```
public function getObjectProperty(object:Object, property:String):Object
{
    var parts:Array = property.split(".");
    if(parts && parts.length == 2 && object && object[parts[0]] && object[parts[0]][parts[1]])
    {
         return object[parts[0]][parts[1]];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is another one that will work with different strings :

```
private function test(e:Event = null):void 
{

    var obj:Object = { 
        "child": { 
            "property":1
         },
         "anotherproperty": 2
    };

    var test1:Object = getObjectProperty(obj, "anotherproperty");
    var test2:Object = getObjectProperty(obj, "child.property");
}

public function getObjectProperty(object:Object, property:String):Object
{
    var parts:Array = property.split(".");
    var returnProp:Object = null;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < parts.length; i++) 
    {
         if(object[parts[i]]) 
         {             
             returnProp = object[parts[i]];
             object = returnProp;
         } 
         else
             return null;
    }

    return returnProp;
}
```

Comment: I know. And already wrote one. But i was thinking is any similar function exist in flex sdk.

Comment: You right. This works. But i suggest to create object copy with ObjectUtil.copy() before modifying object in loop, to keep object instance.

Comment: `object = returnProp` doesn't modify the object outside of the function. It just changes the reference you can confirm by debugging. However if you do something like `object.anotherproperty = 3` inside that function it would change the object outside.